# Wrapping C++ code with SWIG to be used in Processing.org

Tags: java, c++, processing, swig

I'd like to use some C++ libraries in a Processing project but I am not sure how to do it (I am completely newbie in Processing and Java).

The way I proceeded is by using SWIG to create a shared library (.so) that can be then loaded (using the System.load command) in a Java application in the same way as explained in the tutorial:

*http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html*

This might be a super basic question, but my doubt is (I have not been able to find a solution in Google or Stackoverflow) how do I import this library into Processing?

Using the example provided in the link, neither:

```
# I compiled the library with .so rather than .dll, I am using Mac OS X
System.load("/path/to/example.so")
```

nor

```
# Putting the example.so file in the library folder
System.loadLibrary("example")
```

seem to actually import the library. When I try to do something like:

```
double var = example.fact(5);
```

Processing complains saying that "Cannot find anything named example". Could you help me with this? Any hint or resource that explains on how to import `.so` libraries in Processing would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

@Tryskele

Comment: I use [Native](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html) to load C++ libraries in Java. Maybe it could be a good solution for you too.